# How to fit a zoib regression model with random effects from zoib package

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, zero-inflation

Sorry for this likely basic question, but I have been trying to use the 'zoib' package for a while and seem to be unable to do so.
I just want to fit a univariate model with random effects on batches, having zero and one inflation.

```
zoib::zoib(y ~ x1 + x2 + ... | 1,
       model_data,
       zero.inflation = TRUE,
       one.inflation = TRUE,
       random = 1,
       EUID = model_data$batch,
       n.iter = 1050, n.thin = 5, n.burn=50)
```

I constantly get some weird error messages which I seem to be unable to solve.
x.01 undefined, xmu undefined, ...

By adding just plenty | 1 | 1 | ... at the end of the formula makes the model run eventually. But this is unsatisfying and I don't know what it does to the model honestly.

If you understand how to correctly specify this model in the formula, that would be a great help.

Comment: We would probably need some information on your dataset to be of any help here; otherwise, it's pretty just R code (without knowing what error messages really are), which is off-topic per [our FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My problem is related to the correct specification of the formula.
This is not data related. Which is why I did not add it.
But you can use e.g.
data("AlcoholUse", package = "zoib")
eg3 <- zoib::zoib(Percentage ~ Grade + MedDays | 1,
            data = AlcoholUse,
            random = 1,
            EUID= AlcoholUse$County,
            zero.inflation = TRUE,
            one.inflation = TRUE)